# Remove audio from video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I pick a movie with the image picker . The problem is that i don't know how to remove the audio from the asset . Any idea?
This is the code that i am using to retrieve the movie :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *url =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:movie.id]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:movie.id error:nil];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:movie.convertedID error:nil];
    }
    movie.convertedID=nil;

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self saveNewMovieAt:url];
    });

}
```

Comment: did you get any solution so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100284/ios-remove-audio-from-video

Answer (score 1):

better way to **Mute MPMoviePlayerController** while playing instaed of trying to remove the audio from the asset  :)

As per my knowledge, there is no other way to do it..

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];

                          or

        [myMPMoviePlayerController setVolume:0];
```

Comment: this will not work since i am applying some filters on the movie . Also the user can increase the volume .