# iOS (Swift) - Save video without audio

Tags: ios, swift, video, movie

I have a mov video which I am saving in Document Directory. Here, I want to convert video with mute. Because I don't need the sound here. I am using **ALAssetsLibrary().writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum()** to save video. Please help me.

Comment: You can't do so ..... Save your video normally and then mute while playing

Comment: This is not possible with ALAssetsLibrary, you need to use AVFoundation APIs and then remove the audio track from the video composition.

Comment: @TarunTyagi How to remove the audio track from the video composition

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios Jump right in the end where you will find **AVMutableComposition** You'll get a head start. You need to only extract the video track and export. You need to leave out the Audio track while exporting.

Comment: Tarun i looked at AVMutableComposition material But really I cant find the export session where both audio and video tracks are exported. I got your point it can be achieved by this. but I need start..

Comment: I found another thing :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100284/ios-remove-audio-from-video  Is It cool???