# Remove audio from a video file

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to remove the audio track from a MOV type video in my phone's library. I know I can mute the audio on playback, but I plan to upload user videos and it would just make sense to take the audio out and reduce file size.

I've tried converting obj-c code from **[THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100284/ios-remove-audio-from-video)** to swift, but I either messed up with conversion or it just doesn't take out the audio from the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The top upvoted answer didn't work for me + I had issues with video rotation. I ended up modifying the video compression method I had by adding a parameter `muteSound: Bool`.

I use a bitrate of `2300000` to keep the video looking good but 3-4 times smaller in size than original.

I'll keep the question open and mark most upvoted one as correct. Maybe someone can come up with something simpler.

```
func compressVideo(inputURL: NSURL, outputURL: NSURL, bitRate: Int, muteSound: Bool, onDone: () -> ()) {
  let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: inputURL, options: nil)
  let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
  let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
  let videoWriterCompressionSettings = [
    AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: bitRate
  ]

  let videoWriterSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
    AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : videoWriterCompressionSettings,
    AVVideoWidthKey : Int(videoSize.width),
    AVVideoHeightKey : Int(videoSize.height)
  ]

  let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoWriterSettings)
  videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
  videoWriterInput.transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
  let videoWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(URL: outputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)
  videoWriter.addInput(videoWriterInput)

  let videoReaderSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)
  ]

  let videoReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: videoReaderSettings)
  let videoReader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: videoAsset)
  videoReader.addOutput(videoReaderOutput)

  let audioWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: nil)
  audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false
  videoWriter.addInput(audioWriterInput)

  let audioTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
  let audioReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioTrack, outputSettings: nil)
  let audioReader = try! AVAssetReader(asset: videoAsset)
  if muteSound == false {
    audioReader.addOutput(audioReaderOutput)
  }
  videoWriter.startWriting()

  videoReader.startReading()
  videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
  let processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("processingQueue1", nil)
  videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(processingQueue, usingBlock: {() -> Void in
    while videoWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData {
      let sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer? = videoReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
      if videoReader.status == .Reading && sampleBuffer != nil {
        videoWriterInput.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer!)
      } else {
        videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
        if videoReader.status == .Completed {
          if muteSound {
            // return without sound
            videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({() -> Void in
              onDone()
            })
          } else {
            audioReader.startReading()
            videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
            let processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("processingQueue2", nil)

            audioWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(processingQueue, usingBlock: {() -> Void in
              while audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData {
                let sampleBuffer:CMSampleBufferRef? = audioReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
                if audioReader.status == .Reading && sampleBuffer != nil {
                  audioWriterInput.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer!)
                } else {
                  audioWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                  if audioReader.status == .Completed {
                    videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({() -> Void in
                      onDone()
                    })
                  }
                }
              }
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
NSString * initPath1 = VideoLocalPath;
AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

NSString *inputVideoPath = initPath1;

AVURLAsset * sourceAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputVideoPath] options:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

BOOL ok = NO;
AVAssetTrack * sourceVideoTrack = [[sourceAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

CMTimeRange x = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [sourceAsset duration]);

ok = [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:x ofTrack:sourceVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:initPath1]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:initPath1 error:nil];
}

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: initPath1];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    [self savefinalVideoFileToDocuments:exporter.outputURL];
}];


-(void)savefinalVideoFileToDocuments:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationCacheDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Videos"];
    NSData * movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [movieData writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES];
}

- (NSString *)applicationCacheDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return documentsDirectory;
}
```

in swift

```
var initPath1 = VideoLocalPath
var composition = AVMutableComposition.composition()
var inputVideoPath = initPath1
var sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: URL(fileURLWithPath: inputVideoPath), options: nil)
var compositionVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
var ok = false
var sourceVideoTrack = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
var x = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, sourceAsset.duration)
do {
    ok = try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(x, of: sourceVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
}
catch let error {
}
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: initPath1) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: initPath1)
    }
    catch let error {
    }
}
var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: initPath1)
var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exporter.outputURL = url


func savefinalVideoFile(toDocuments url: URL) {
    var storePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.applicationCacheDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Videos")!.absoluteString
    var movieData = Data(contentsOf: url)
    movieData.write(toFile: storePath, atomically: true)
}

func applicationCacheDirectory() -> String {
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory = (paths.count > 0) ? paths[0] : nil
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: seems like it's exactly the same code I mentioned in the question (didn't check word for word). I need a swift version since I tried converting this to swift with no success.

Comment: thanks for converting... I'll try it out now and get back to you

Comment: sorry, there were just too many errors when I copied the code, but it helped me get closer to something that works

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for my project, this works well for portrait video can also be tweaked for landscape as well.

```
    func removeSound(withFileURLs videoFileURL: URL, completion: @escaping (_ mergedVideoURL: URL?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        guard let videoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
            completion(nil, videoTrackError())
            return
        }
        var instructions = [AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol]()
        var isError = false
        var currentTime: CMTime = CMTime.zero
        var videoSize = CGSize.zero
        var highestFrameRate = 0

            let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true]
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoFileURL, options: options)
            guard let videoAsset: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
                return
            }
            if videoSize.equalTo(CGSize.zero) {
                videoSize = (videoAsset.naturalSize)
            }
            var isVideoAssetPortrait_ = false
            let videoTransform: CGAffineTransform = videoAsset.preferredTransform

            if videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0 {
                isVideoAssetPortrait_ = true
            }
            if videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0 {
                isVideoAssetPortrait_ = true
            }

            var videoAssetWidth: CGFloat = videoAsset.naturalSize.width
            var videoAssetHeight: CGFloat = videoAsset.naturalSize.height
            if isVideoAssetPortrait_ {
                videoAssetWidth = videoAsset.naturalSize.height
                videoAssetHeight = videoAsset.naturalSize.width
            }
            videoSize.height = (videoAssetHeight)
            videoSize.width = (videoAssetWidth)

            let currentFrameRate = Int(roundf((videoAsset.nominalFrameRate)))
            highestFrameRate = (currentFrameRate > highestFrameRate) ? currentFrameRate : highestFrameRate
            let timeRange: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: asset.duration)
            do {
                try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: videoAsset, at: currentTime)
                let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction.init()
                videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: currentTime, duration: timeRange.duration)
                let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)

                var isVideoAssetPortrait_ = false
                let videoTransform: CGAffineTransform = videoAsset.preferredTransform
                var videoAssetOrientation_: UIImage.Orientation = .up
                if videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0 {
                    videoAssetOrientation_ = .right
                    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = true
                }
                if videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0 {
                    videoAssetOrientation_ = .left
                    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = true
                }
                if videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0 {
                    videoAssetOrientation_ = .up
                }
                if videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0 {
                    videoAssetOrientation_ = .down
                }

                var videoAssetWidth: CGFloat = videoAsset.naturalSize.width
                var videoAssetHeight: CGFloat = videoAsset.naturalSize.height
                if isVideoAssetPortrait_ {
                    videoAssetWidth = videoAsset.naturalSize.height
                    videoAssetHeight = videoAsset.naturalSize.width
                }
                var tx: Int = 0
                if videoSize.width - videoAssetWidth != 0 {
                    tx = Int((videoSize.width - videoAssetWidth) / 2)
                }
                var ty: Int = 0
                if videoSize.height - videoAssetHeight != 0 {
                    ty = Int((videoSize.height - videoAssetHeight) / 2)
                }
                var Scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                var factor : CGFloat = 1.0
                if tx != 0 && ty != 0 {
                    if tx <= ty {
                        factor = CGFloat(videoSize.width / videoAssetWidth)
                        Scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(factor), y: CGFloat(factor))
                        tx = 0
                        ty = Int((videoSize.height - videoAssetHeight * CGFloat(factor)) / 2)
                    }
                    if tx > ty {
                        factor = CGFloat(videoSize.height / videoAssetHeight)
                        Scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(factor), y: CGFloat(factor))
                        ty = 0
                        tx = Int((videoSize.width - videoAssetWidth * CGFloat(factor)) / 2)
                    }
                }

                var Move: CGAffineTransform!
                var transform: CGAffineTransform!
                switch videoAssetOrientation_ {
                case UIImage.Orientation.right:
                    Move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: (videoAssetWidth * factor) + CGFloat(tx)  , y: CGFloat(ty))
                    transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:degreeToRadian(90))
                    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform.concatenating(Scale.concatenating(Move)), at: .zero)
                case UIImage.Orientation.left:
                    Move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: CGFloat(tx), y: videoSize.height - CGFloat(ty))
                    transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreeToRadian(270))
                    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform.concatenating(Scale.concatenating(Move)), at: .zero)
                case UIImage.Orientation.up:
                    Move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: CGFloat(tx), y: CGFloat(ty))
                    layerInstruction.setTransform(Scale.concatenating(Move), at: .zero)
                case UIImage.Orientation.down:
                    Move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: videoSize.width + CGFloat(tx), y: (videoAssetHeight*factor)+CGFloat(ty))
                    transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreeToRadian(180))
                    layerInstruction.setTransform(transform.concatenating(Scale.concatenating(Move)), at: .zero)
                default:
                    break
                }

                videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
                instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)
                currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, timeRange.duration)
            } catch {
                print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
                isError = true
                completion(nil, error)
            }

        if isError == false {
            let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            let strFilePath: String = generateMergedVideoFilePath()
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: strFilePath)
            exportSession?.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: strFilePath)
            exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp4
            exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            let mutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition.init()
            mutableVideoComposition.instructions = instructions
            mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(highestFrameRate))
            mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = videoSize
            exportSession?.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition
            let exportCompletion: (() -> Void) = {() -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                    completion(exportSession?.outputURL, exportSession?.error)
                })
            }
            if let exportSession = exportSession {
                exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
                    switch exportSession.status {
                    case .completed:
                        print("Successfully merged")
                        exportCompletion()
                    case .failed:
                        print("Failed")
                        exportCompletion()
                    case .cancelled:
                        print("Cancelled")
                        exportCompletion()
                    case .unknown:
                        print("Unknown")
                    case .exporting:
                        print("Exporting")
                    case .waiting:
                        print("Wating")
                    }

                })
            }
        }
    }

func videoTrackError() -> Error {
        let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] =
            [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey :  NSLocalizedString("error", value: "Provide correct video file", comment: "") ,
              NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : NSLocalizedString("error", value: "No video track available", comment: "")]
        return NSError(domain: "VideoMerger", code: 404, userInfo: (userInfo as! [String : Any]))
    }

    func generateMergedVideoFilePath() -> String {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: ((FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last)?.path)!).appendingPathComponent("\(UUID().uuidString)-soundlessVideo.mp4").path
    }
    func degreeToRadian(_ degree: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return (.pi * degree / 180.0)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3,

```
func removeAudioFromVideo(_ videoPath: String) {
   let initPath1: String = videoPath
   let composition = AVMutableComposition()
   let inputVideoPath: String = initPath1
   let sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: inputVideoPath), options: nil)
   let compositionVideoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
   let sourceVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
   let x: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, sourceAsset.duration)
   _ = try? compositionVideoTrack!.insertTimeRange(x, of: sourceVideoTrack!, at: kCMTimeZero)
   if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: initPath1) {
       try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: initPath1)
   }
   let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: initPath1)
   let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
   exporter?.outputURL = url
   exporter?.outputFileType = "com.apple.quicktime-movie"
   exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
       self.saveFinalVideoFile(toDocuments: exporter!.outputURL!)
   })
}

func saveFinalVideoFile(toDocuments url: URL) {
   let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("Videos")
   let movieData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
   try? movieData?.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
}
```