# Ask multiple system permissions combined

Tags: ios, swift

need some help regarding iOS dev..swift 5

1. Is there any way in swift 5 to combine 3 system permission alerts(camera, microphone and photos)  in a single alert?

Using AVCaptureDevice for camera and microphone access and PHPhotoLibrary for photos access...

2. Is there any way to record a muted video? (I want to record video without audio and not ask for microphone permissions)

Answer (score 2):

1. No there is no way to ask for more than one permission at a time  (Like in Android). Typically in iOS you ask for the permission only when its needed, but this can be tricky when the whole purpose of your app is to use the camera or microphone.

   A common design practise in this situation is to have an onboarding screen / flow, that only shows up the first time the user opens the app. Here you present the user with a screen explaining that certain permissions are required. Present a button for each permission, and when tapped, trigger the specific permissions dialog.

   When all permissions granted, enable a continue button that brings you to your app homepage.
2. There is no way to record a video without sound. You will need to record
   the video and then remove the sound. There are a few questions / answers on stackoverflow with sample code to do the same, here is one such example: [Ios: Remove audio from video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100284/ios-remove-audio-from-video)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way to ask for multiple permissions at a time in iOS. But you can do something like create a single UI with an action button for each permission. And ask for permission accordingly when the user clicks on the button.